# Why is the c++ program outputting a wrong negative number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  
  int woe; // weight on earth
  int wom = woe * 2; // weight on mars
  
  std::cout << "Enter your weight on earth: \n";
  std::cin >> woe;

  std::cout << "Your weight on mars would be " << wom << " Pounds\n";
    
}
```

Hello everyone I just started to learn c++ and when I try to multiply the variable "woe" by 2 it prints a big negative number like "-2123145280 Pounds" when I input 100. please help thank.

Comment: woe is uninitialized at the moment of computing wom. This is not Excel.

Comment: `int wom = woe * 2` If you think this means "wom is defined as woe times two, whatever value woe might assume in the future" then you are mistaken. C++ doesn't work like this. Please review what your book says about the assignment operator. By the way, your weight on Mars is about *one half* of your weight on Earth, rather than twice as much.

Comment: yes i just use website to learn and I was just testing * 2 because the correct one was not work

Comment: Think carefully about the logical steps needed to solve the problem. Which should happen first: finding out the value to multiply, or multiplying it? Why? (Imagine if you were trying to do this task yourself. Could you do the multiplication before asking me? How?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you just define an integer variable without assignment in C++ it takes a random number, then you are just doubling that random number in wom variable and after that you take input. A more correct version of your code is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int woe = 0; // weight on earth

  std::cout << "Enter your weight on earth: \n";
  std::cin >> woe;

  int wom = woe * 2; // weight on mars
  std::cout << "Your weight on mars would be " << wom << " Pounds\n";
}
```